# installing multiple apks at once

Tags: android, apk

I wanted to install multiple APKs at a time because I am having one main app that does everything and all the other apps have a service and an activity that has to be put on the device for the main one to run, would it be best to include them in a zip I know something like this happens because su.zip does something similar

Comment: Since installing "multiple APKs at a time" is not really supported, why are they separate apps in the first place? If they all need to be installed, simply combine them into one app.

Comment: If the main app requires these other apps to run, why not do as CommonsWare says and consolidate them into one app? It'd save you the headache of multiple installs and downrating on the Market because of a non-functional app.

Comment: I disagree with CommonsWare, he might want to have these other APKs because of JVM size or that he is maybe writing a separate Provider.  For all we know he is writing an Enterprise app(s).

Comment: probably should have explained this better but it will not be going in the market place, i just wanted to make it easier from giving it to each person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do something like this for updating my multiple Enterprise APKs.  I downloaded the APK from a REST API/ database.  Then once I had the file I started the install of the app in program by calling:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This will start the installer and install the APK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb via console/cmd "adb install com.example". 
Which OS are you running? Write a little script to install them all.

Comment: You could probably script some adb commands, but I would not recommend it because this isn't something you could do for commercial release.