# Android studio compile error showing “Content is not allowed in prolog”

Tags: android, compiler-errors, resources

I use latest Android Studio 1.3.2 (for OS windows 7), in "asset" directory I put 2 apks  and when I try to compile I receive this error.

```
D:\Work On Android\LocalRepo\CSipSimple-master\app\src\main\res\assets\CSipSimpleCodecPack_1.5.apk
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\Work On Android\LocalRepo\CSipSimple-master\app\src\main\res\assets\CSipSimpleCodecPack_1.5.apk:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

How can I solve this error ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to run my project . When I want to run my project I ge tthis error .

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my question, why do you want apk in assets folder?

Comment: At the time of installation of my apk , two new apk will be installed . That is why , I need apk in assets folder .

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to understand. WHY?

Comment: At the time of installation of my apk , two new apk will be installed . That is why , I need apk in assets folder .

Comment: It's not possible to install other apks without user's consent. Although if you are ok with manual installation then have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11639291/5352802

Comment: Two apks are presented to users to be installed . I have sucessfully done that .

Comment: OK then in that case the above mention answer is what you should do

Comment: What can I do to solve this error ?

Comment: You cannot have it in assets it seems. You'll have to get it from server.

Comment: But I have done it with Android studio 1.0.1 . What is the problem in Android studio 1.3.2 ?

Comment: Have a look at Henry's answer below and also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23557171/5352802

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967831/org-gradle-api-uncheckedioexception-failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input/54594998#54594998?newreg=f10556ce296f4876a098937901c7aa84

Answer (score 5):

You cannot invent new resource directories. The issue is that you can't create an `assets` folder inside the `main\res` folder. You need to move the `assets` folder to the `main` folder.