# mergeDebugResources error - how to fix that?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: logcat screenshot]

How can I fix this error that bothers me?

**error log** :

> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' property 'aapt2FromMaven' during up-to-date check.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:331)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:151)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:111)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:208)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:93)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:50)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
>       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:72)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:55)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:329)
>       ... 36 more
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.2.1-4818971/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :app
>       at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:108)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:93)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:60)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.resolve(ComponentState.java:163)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.ComponentState.getMetaData(ComponentState.java:174)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.calculateTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:137)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.attachToTargetConfigurations(EdgeState.java:108)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.attachToTargetRevisionsSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:236)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:226)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:140)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:111)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:92)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:146)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:73)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:494)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:485)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:470)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:120)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:927)
>       at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:915)
>       ... 43 more

Comment: First paste error log here, it's not visible on  your screenshot

Comment: I can't paste it at the comment but i edited the question you can check the log there

Comment: Firstly format your error log into code and did you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967831/org-gradle-api-uncheckedioexception-failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input

Comment: Thank You very much it's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Android Studio` settings and find `Android SDK`, then update (or make full install) `Support Repository`. After that `Android Studio` settings and `Invalidate caches and restart`.